# How does Google Drive Terminate editing session

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, editing

I have a cloud storage application where I store my documents. I am integrating google drive API to enable co-editing of documents.

So the goal is that the users can edit the documents stored in my cloud with google editing. I have implemented a feature to allow push notifications.

I see that when I close the document, I don't get any notification to end the session. I wanted to know if there is a way to terminate the session. Is there any way to distinguish this end of the session thingy?

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to catch the end session the send a notification to other users that e.g. "User has logged out and finished editing". I think it is not yet possible to handle that event to send notification, check [Understanding Drive API notification events](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#understanding-drive-api-notification-events) for the list of events that you can use for notification. Also check [Google Drive API Push Notifications](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-drive-api-push-notifications.html) blog for info.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot for the reply :-)